# How exactly would I make my custom list view accessible in the same way as a comctl32 listview in report mode?

Tags: listview, winapi, accessibility

I'm building a custom list view control that only supports report mode; I'm doing this because the standard list view is not adequate. I want to make this accessible. I've read a lot of stuff so far ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971338.aspx), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307847.aspx), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971325)), but I'm still unsure of how to make things work exactly like the real listview control.

In particular:

- How do I take the header control into account? This is the standard comctl32 header control with no modifications or subclassing/superclassing. Would I just present each row as a series of columns named after the header cell names? What about for the purpose of hit testing? What about the scrollbars, which are the standard non-client `WM_HSCROLL`/`WM_VSCROLL` scrollbars?
- How would I navigate to each column of a row? The standard control can only select rows at a time; there's no column selection or column sorting.
- How do I make images in an image list accessible?
- One feature of my custom list view is the ability to have columns that contain only checkboxes. There can be more than one such column in the control. How would I expose that to accessible clients?
- And finally, how would I make it so that the accessible client treats this custom control like an ordinary list view? For instance, what exactly should the name and value properties of the list view and its rows be? What about the parent/children? (Should I just defer to a standard accessibility proxy for these?)

I want to run on at least all versions of Windows XP with Common Controls 6, so I'm currently aiming for MSAA. If what I want is better suited for UI Automation, however, I can see what I can do...

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to all your 8 questions is "by programming it". Write the code, then come back and ask specific questions if you have problems.

Comment: What exactly is not adequate about the standard ListView? It can do column selection and column sorting via its `LVN_COLUMNCLICK` notification. Putting checkboxes in a column can be done with owner drawing. As for how a ListView represents itself to MSAA, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318554.aspx).

Comment: Personally, I would use a standard ListView, subclassing it to catch the `WM_GETOBJECT` message so you can return a custom `IAccessible` proxy object that delegates to the ListView's standard `IAccessible` object for standard fields but overrides its behavior as needed, such as for your custom checkbox columns.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - I'm asking how to write the code =P or rather, what I would need to write to get it to work properly

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I want to do things the standard listview cannot do: specifically images, text, and checkboxes in any column (but only one of the three per column); I tried doing this with a subclassed listview already and the limitations of the control make this too buggy to be feasible

Comment: I use owner-drawn ListViews, they work just fine. So you are likely just not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Inspect utility to look this up myself.

I have no idea how images or checkboxes are handled, but I can say that the list items and the header are children, the `accName` is the item text, the `accDescription` is a string consisting of "Column Text: Subitem Text" pairs for the subitems, and no `accValue`, among other things.

My own control doesn't quite fit this model, since it has checkboxes on any column, so the list cells have to be navigable anyway, somehow (for instance, with the keyboard). I might just use the accessible tables link in my original post instead... will have to investigate that myself. Thanks in the meantime!